# setup module url : no go-import meta tags

Tags: go

Please consider this question:

Based on https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/call-module-code, I've:

```
$ cat hello.go 
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "example.com/greetings"
)

func main() {
    // Get a greeting message and print it.
    message := greetings.Hello("Gladys")
    fmt.Println(message)
}
```

and,

```
$ cat go.mod 
module hello

go 1.14

replace example.com/greetings => ../greetings

require example.com/greetings v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
```

It loads the `greetings` module from my local folder, and goes its way.

In real life, `greetings` is a module I use a lot, so I lug that folder around a lot so I can use my it.

To avoid this, how can I setup my own URL of this folder, and use it? That is, I can copy that  folder to say, `https://mywebsite.com/myGoThings/greeting` - just a plain apache server which is open for GETs. (I do not want to use github, I'd prefer my own https endpoint.)

When I try this, `go get mywebsite.com/myGoThings/greeting` complains :  `no go-import meta tags ()` and quits.

If this is possible, could you please show me how to accomplish this?

**update 1**

This is my greetings folder as in  `mywebsite.com/myGoThings/greeting`:

```
$ ls greetings/
go.mod  greetings.go  import.html
```

import.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <!-- Go Imports -->
  <meta name="go-import" content="GOIMPORT">
  <meta name="go-source" content="GOSOURCE">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; REDIRECT">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have any custom domain else github.com, gitlab.com, etc. The first step is to add a ssh-key to your system, then set the GOPRIVATE environment variable. after a logoff you can use your own private repository.
[The official golang documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_configuration_for_non_public_modules) describes how to that.

Comment: Thanks Nima Ghoroubi. pls see update in question. What should `GOIMPORT` `GOSOURCE` and `REDIRECT` be, in my `import.html` above? not familiar with Jekyll

Comment: The process of setting those variables values is described  here: https://sagikazarmark.hu/blog/vanity-import-paths-in-go/